# How to log all headers of request/response in Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, logging, tomcat7

I'm trying to log all headers of request/response in Tomcat 7. I tried to use [access-log-valve](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve). But as mentioned in the link, we can print headers only one by one. We have to specify each and every header we need.

e.g.

```
pattern="%{User-Agent}i %{Content-Type}i %{Accept}i %{Accept-Encoding}i
%{Accept-Language}i %{Accept-Charset}i %r %h %q"
```

Isn't there a way to log all headers at once, may be using a wildcard?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way out of the box - but an easy alternative is to stuff run a filter. The filter shove's all the headers you want into the servlet request. Then use "%{foo}r" in your pattern where foo is the name of the variable in the servlet request.

Comment: there is - maybe was not back then - see other answers

Answer (score 8):

Inital **important** hint, **especially for production environments**: be careful **enabling the filter** since it **may harm your request param encoding**! So maybe be sure to set up everything right by maybe setting up the [org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35505560/1915920) first!

---

From ***Tomcat 7*+** on you should do it via [filters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5672980/1915920):

- in **`web.xml`**

```xml
    <filter>
        <filter-name>requestdumper</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.apache.catalina.filters.RequestDumperFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>requestdumper</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

and then log it e.g. to some special log file like this in **`CATALINA_BASE/conf/logging.properties`** (modified based on [Tomcat 7 docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#Request_Dumper_Filter)):

```bash
## this may likely be your (to-be-updated) orig handlers declaration:
#handlers = \
#   1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler\
#  ,2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler\
#  ,3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler\
#  ,4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler\
#  ,java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

## ... and you have to add your 1request-dumper:
handlers = \
   1request-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler\
  ,1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler\
  ,2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler\
  ,3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler\
  ,4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler\
  ,java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler


## ...


# To this configuration below, 1request-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
# also needs to be added to the handlers property near the top of the file
1request-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = INFO
1request-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1request-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = localhost_access_log.req-dumps.
1request-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.encoding = UTF-8
1request-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.formatter = org.apache.juli.VerbatimFormatter
org.apache.catalina.filters.RequestDumperFilter.level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.filters.RequestDumperFilter.handlers = \
  1request-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
```

---

Till ***Tomcat 6* and before** you could use the **`RequestDumperValve`** (as in [Brian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42237788/1915920)):

add this to your **`server.xml`**:

```xml
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestDumperValve"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

[David Lee](http://robobruin.blogspot.com/2007/09/logging-request-and-response-headers-in.html) says add this to your `server.xml`:

`<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestDumperValve"/>`

Comment: RequestDumperValue is not available in Tomcat 7: [Tomcat 7 Valves](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html)

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Request Dumper Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.RequestDumperFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Request Dumper Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

This will log request and response headers in cataline.out log file:

```
==> /usr/local/tomcat/logs/catalina.out <==
2020-06-10 12:20:47.844 INFO  [RequestDumperFilter] - http-nio-8080-exec-9 START TIME        =10-Jun-2020 12:20:47
2020-06-10 12:20:47.845 INFO  [RequestDumperFilter] - http-nio-8080-exec-9         requestURI=/myservice/health
2020-06-10 12:20:47.845 INFO  [RequestDumperFilter] - http-nio-8080-exec-9           authType=null
2020-06-10 12:20:47.846 INFO  [RequestDumperFilter] - http-nio-8080-exec-9  characterEncoding=null
2020-06-10 12:20:47.846 INFO  [RequestDumperFilter] - http-nio-8080-exec-9      contentLength=-1
2020-06-10 12:20:47.847 INFO  [RequestDumperFilter] - http-nio-8080-exec-9        contentType=null
2020-06-10 12:20:47.847 INFO  [RequestDumperFilter] - http-nio-8080-exec-9        contextPath=/myservice
2020-06-10 12:20:47.848 INFO  [RequestDumperFilter] - http-nio-8080-exec-9             header=host=192.168.99.200:9080
2020-06-10 12:20:47.849 INFO  [RequestDumperFilter] - http-nio-8080-exec-9             header=accept=text/plain, text/*, */*
2020-06-10 12:20:47.849 INFO  [RequestDumperFilter] - http-nio-8080-exec-9             header=accept-encoding=gzip
2020-06-10 12:20:47.850 INFO  [RequestDumperFilter] - http-nio-8080-exec-9             header=connection=close
2020-06-10 12:20:47.850 INFO  [RequestDumperFilter] - http-nio-8080-exec-9             locale=en_US
2020-06-10 12:20:47.851 INFO  [RequestDumperFilter] - http-nio-8080-exec-9             method=GET
2020-06-10 12:20:47.851 INFO  [RequestDumperFilter] - http-nio-8080-exec-9           pathInfo=null
2020-06-10 12:20:47.851 INFO  [RequestDumperFilter] - http-nio-8080-exec-9           protocol=HTTP/1.1
2020-06-10 12:20:47.852 INFO  [RequestDumperFilter] - http-nio-8080-exec-9        queryString=null
2020-06-10 12:20:47.852 INFO  [RequestDumperFilter] - http-nio-8080-exec-9         remoteAddr=172.18.0.1
2020-06-10 12:20:47.853 INFO  [RequestDumperFilter] - http-nio-8080-exec-9         remoteHost=172.18.0.1
2020-06-10 12:20:47.853 INFO  [RequestDumperFilter] - http-nio-8080-exec-9 requestedSessionId=null
2020-06-10 12:20:47.854 INFO  [RequestDumperFilter] - http-nio-8080-exec-9             scheme=https
2020-06-10 12:20:47.854 INFO  [RequestDumperFilter] - http-nio-8080-exec-9         serverName=192.168.99.200
2020-06-10 12:20:47.855 INFO  [RequestDumperFilter] - http-nio-8080-exec-9         serverPort=443
2020-06-10 12:20:47.855 INFO  [RequestDumperFilter] - http-nio-8080-exec-9        servletPath=/health
2020-06-10 12:20:47.856 INFO  [RequestDumperFilter] - http-nio-8080-exec-9           isSecure=true
2020-06-10 12:20:47.856 INFO  [RequestDumperFilter] - http-nio-8080-exec-9 ------------------=--------------------------------------------
2020-06-10 12:20:47.857 INFO  [RequestDumperFilter] - http-nio-8080-exec-9 ------------------=--------------------------------------------
2020-06-10 12:20:47.857 INFO  [RequestDumperFilter] - http-nio-8080-exec-9           authType=null
2020-06-10 12:20:47.857 INFO  [RequestDumperFilter] - http-nio-8080-exec-9        contentType=application/json;charset=UTF-8
2020-06-10 12:20:47.858 INFO  [RequestDumperFilter] - http-nio-8080-exec-9             status=200
2020-06-10 12:20:47.858 INFO  [RequestDumperFilter] - http-nio-8080-exec-9 END TIME          =10-Jun-2020 12:20:47
2020-06-10 12:20:47.858 INFO  [RequestDumperFilter] - http-nio-8080-exec-9 ===============================================================
```

Tested on Tomcat 8 on Centos 7.