# How can I identify the reason for an http 400 error code tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, http-headers, http-status-code-400

We are getting intermittent 400 response errors to some of our requests and I have tried to track down what is the cause of the 400.  The access log from tomcat shows the 400 response.  So I added in the request-dumper filter for tomcat.   Looking at the logs, I'm not getting anything from this filter for when the 400 occurs.  In the request-dumper log, the information for the requests that succeeded that were immediately before and after this error are in log, but nothing for the request that generated a 400 response.  I'm looking for suggestions on what/how to track this down in tomcat.  I thought the request-dumper would do it, but as I said nothing is generated in that log.

Comment: 400 is a bad request.  The fact that you say there is nothing for the request that generated the 400 seems to be an answer itself.

Comment: The tomcat access log has the get URL listed with a 400 response.  We can use that same URL and paste in a browser and it works.

Comment: But was there supposed to be something sent and it's not?  i.e. is this a call that is expecting, for example, a POST body of JSON and it's not there?

Comment: It's a get request.  I've done research into potential reasons for a 400.  URL is good.  Sometimes the exact same thing works.  I want to see, are we overrunning our cookies?  Is our length that we are say we are sending different than what we actually send?    So I need to see what the actual headers are sending. What are the cookies...

Comment: What version of Tomcat are you using?  According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17545691/how-to-log-all-headers-of-request-response-in-tomcat-7/19732912) the headers should be dumped.

Comment: looks like 7.0.63

Comment: I have the same issue with tomcat9 @Laura did you finally figured out the cause?

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue after upgrading the tomcat from Tomcat_7 to Tomcat_9 for our API. The same code was working fine in version 7. It is a GET call from a frontend application which makes a to the API which is running on TC_9. Now the Tomcat-9 that hosts the API is rejecting the call with 400 bad request

One thing to note - One of the query parameter in the URL has a lot of (around 60-70) comma separated values like this https://?custId=value1&attribute=v1,v2,v3,v4,..........,v70

Due to this Total number of text characters in the entire URL is around 4000+