# Hybris how to log Redirections

Tags: redirect, logging, sap-commerce-cloud

I need to LOG redirections , however not all the redirections of the page , only the ones that happen in a Method or a Page or something more specific , how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Some re-directions made by Spring, some of them made by OOTB code. So you cannot get all of them in your code.
I prefer doing this on load balancer side or [tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17545691/how-to-log-all-headers-of-request-response-in-tomcat-7/19732912).