# How to log the sessionId in the Tomcat console log?

Tags: tomcat, logging

When server (500) errors occur in tomcat we get at least 2 log entries:

1. One in the access Log
2. One or more messages (and/or stack traces) in the Console Log

In order to correlate errors in the console with access errors we would like to use the [`User session ID` which we get with `%S`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/config/valve.html#:%7E:text=%25S%20%2D-,User%20session%20ID,-%25t%20%2D%20Date%20and) (server.xml) in the access log.

How can we get the session id in the console?

Comment: If I may suggest another solution to correlate.. You can correlate the thread-name which appears in the console with the one you can explicitly log with an [Extended Access Log Valve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/valve.html#Extended_Access_Log_Valve/Attributes), the attribute being *x-threadname* Usually, code out of control or too much technical debt lead to that correlation need.

Comment: Thanks, that helps narrow things down but of course the same thread serves many different sessions.

Comment: One thread is serving one client at the same time. You can play with the connector settings to increase the thread pool and make it not so likely to have exceptions that you will not be able to match between the 2 logs. Divide/Conquer often works.

Comment: True, but the time in the access and console logs do not exactly match. If that were the case threadId+timestamp would be a good correlation key.

Comment: [Guard the log file](https://geek-and-poke.com/geekandpoke/2021/3/16/simply-explained) well... _very_ well...

Answer (score 1):

Activate the [Request Dumper Filter](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/filter.html#Request_Dumper_Filter) with the sample configuration given in this doc.

As you want to see in the console log (a better idea than a dedicated log ?), you need to change the handler to :

```
org.apache.catalina.filters.RequestDumperFilter.handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

You then should see things like that in catalina.out giving both JSESSIONDID and the status code (500 in your case) :

```
06-Feb-2019 16:59:40.499 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.filters.RequestDumperFilter.doLog http-nio-8080-exec-1             header=Set-Cookie=JSESSIONID=E44588D6574AB1489540509E2A710934; Path=/manager; HttpOnly
..
06-Feb-2019 16:59:40.499 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.filters.RequestDumperFilter.doLog http-nio-8080-exec-1             status=200
```

You might have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8727615/7748072) too.