# Tomcat filter in web.xml gets triggered when sending OPTIONS from Postman but not when sending OPTIONS from browser or curl

Tags: java, tomcat, cors

Tomcat (hosts my java back-end API) has this filter:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>ApiOriginFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>io.swagger.api.ApiOriginFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ApiOriginFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

which is this java code (I added the System.out.println("Test"); part):

```
package io.swagger.api;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "io.swagger.codegen.v3.generators.java.JavaJerseyServerCodegen", date = "2020-01-07T08:47:08.031Z[GMT]")public class ApiOriginFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");
        res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        System.out.println("Test");
    }

    public void destroy() {}

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}
}
```

I have an Ionic/React/Typescript application that I am building that performs the following API call the the Java API:

```
const apiClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://10.0.29.1:8080/swagger-jaxrs-server.1.0.0/v1/',
    responseType: 'json',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'
    }
});
const createUser = async (newUser: NewUser) => {
  try {
    const response = await apiClient.post<User>('/users', newUser);
    const user = response.data;
    return user;
  } catch (err) {
    if (err && err.response) {
      const axiosError = err as AxiosError<ServerError>
      if (axiosError.response)
      {
        return axiosError.response.data;
      }
      else
      {
        return 0;
      }
    }
```

It simply POSTS to "http://10.0.29.1:8080/swagger-jaxrs-server.1.0.0/v1/users". When this call is being performed in Chrome and Firefox I get the following response:

**Chrome OPTIONS response**:
[image]
**Firefox OPTIONS response**:
[image]

Both browsers of course complain about CORS (there is no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the `OPTIONS` response headers):

**Firefox CORS warning**:
[image]
**Chrome CORS warning**
[image]

When I do the same thing in POSTMAN:

[image]

it works.

Going to `/opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out` I get this:

[image]

The "Test" lines are from when I am POSTing from Postman. It is the System.out.println("Test"); code that I added in the ApiOriginFilter.java function. Means that the filter gets triggered when Postman sends OPTIONS. What is going on in the case of the browsers? Where is this response coming from and why is the filter not being triggered?

UPDATE: If I copy and paste the headers that Firefox/Chrome sents with the OPTIONS request to Postman, Postman still works. If I copy the Postman headers in a `headers.txt` file:

```
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.21.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: b3b6ae69-58fe-44dc-bdf0-7280679f0f32
Host: 10.0.29.1:8080
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
```

and then perform curl -H @headers.txt -i -X OPTIONS http://10.0.29.1:8080/swagger-jaxrs-server.1.0.0/v1/users it responds

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Allow: OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, POST
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 10 Jan 2020 06:47:45 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=20
Connection: keep-alive
```

which means the filter is not being called. If I simply `curl -i -X OPTIONS http://10.0.29.1:8080/swagger-jaxrs-server.1.0.0/v1/users` it responds

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Allow: OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, POST
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 10 Jan 2020 06:51:37 GMT
```

still the filter is not being called.

Comment: Could it be that your Postman request differs in terms of attributes, comparing to what browsers send? General suggestion is to keep them exactly the same.

Comment: I agree but i dont control the browser OPTIONS call, its done automatically by the browser

Comment: But you do control your Postman.

Comment: I copied and pasted all the headers from Firefox/Chrome to Postman and I sent the request, it still works from Postman

Comment: Not sure if it is related, but does your Typescript add two slashes to the URL? Like "//users". Also, try to add `@WebFilter(urlPatterns = {"/*"})` to your filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was one of those cases where a typo can make you wonder for hours. If you notice, the URL in Postman is `http://10.0.29.1:8080/swagger-jaxrs-server-1.0.0/v1/` while in the source code it is `http://10.0.29.1:8080/swagger-jaxrs-server.1.0.0/v1/`. The `.` character between `server` and `1` is wrong, it should have been a `-`. I was also using the wrong address in cURL because I was copying it from the source code. At some point I even had two identical (to me) Postman OPTIONS requests, one working and one not working (!).

Here is how I brought myself to notice it:

First I added the RequestDumperFilter (Tomcat 7 or later) to the `web.xml` file of my webapp (located in `/opt/tomcat/webapps/<your-webapp>/WEB-INF/web.xml`, in order to capture all the HTTP headers (request/response), like this

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>requestdumper</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.apache.catalina.filters.RequestDumperFilter
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>requestdumper</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

and in the `/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties` file I added a logging handler for the filter like this:

```
handlers = ..., 5request-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
...
5request-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINEST
5request-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
5request-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = request-dumper.
5request-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.formatter = org.apache.juli.VerbatimFormatter
org.apache.catalina.filters.RequestDumperFilter.level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.filters.RequestDumperFilter.handlers = 5request-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
```

credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8727615/1238675

However after `sudo service tomcat restart` the filter was not capturing the erroneous browser/curl requests at all. I then put the filter in `/opt/tomcat/conf/web.xml` so that it would capture any request made to Tomcat, not just my webapp. Indeed I started capturing the headers and I put side by side the logs caused by Postman and the logs caused by the browser:

[image]

It can be noticed that `contextPath`, `pathInfo` and `servletPath` are all wrong in the left side. This made me to immediately (finally) take a look at the URL and there you have it.