# Read jsp page output from my application

Tags: java, jsp

I would like to read jsp page from my application and save it to a file - it's output, not the code itself. Plus, my application has basic authentication (username+password).

If it was a Servlet, I could just access it's doGet method.

One solution I've found is [this](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-connect-to-a-url-using-basic-authentication.html) - Open URL connection, provide authentication details and read the stream.

I'm wondering if there's another option, maybe accessing the generated Servlet in the web container and then using reflection to call the class doGet.

Comment: If you want to do it for logging purposes, this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158647/logging-response-body-html-from-httpservletresponse-using-spring-mvc-handlerin

Answer (score 1):

You can precompile the JSP and then call the servlet (you don't have to use reflection even).
If you try to call the JSP's servlet without precompiling then it might not exit yet (because usually the server only compiles the JSP after it was called for the first time).

To precompile the JSP, check your web server documentation.

Personally I think you're better of using URL connection. Precompiling JSPs is not portable (as in you need to do it in a different way for each web server).

**Edit**

You can also use `RequestDispatcher.include()` method with a wrapped response object as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1076056/162056).