# get ServletResponse content string for logging

Tags: java, spring, logging, filter, servlet-filters

I have a RESTful service developed by Java Spring. I created some filters for authentications, get some custom headers, etc. etc. in one of the filters I need to log incoming Request and outgoing Response. Right now I stuck in logging the response. here is the filter

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException
```

`servletResponse` is the object that I need to get the content.

I know there are some duplicate questions that already answered but for some reason none of those works for me.

I have a `filter` and in `doFilter` method after `chain.doFilter` I want to log the response content.

I can see the `JSON` object when I'm inspecting the `response` in `outputStream` or in `writer`. But I cannot get it programmatically.

Can someone help me to resolve this? Thank you in advance!

Here are the links that I used and didn't help:

[How to read and copy the HTTP servlet response output stream content for logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933054/how-to-log-response-content-from-a-java-web-server)

[Capture and log the response body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242236/capture-and-log-the-response-body)

[Logging response body (HTML) from HttpServletResponse using Spring MVC HandlerInterceptorAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158647/logging-response-body-html-from-httpservletresponse-using-spring-mvc-handlerin)

Comment: Did you try something already? Do you have some code?

Comment: I will edit my question and will include all codes that I tried and didn't help

Comment: How exactly did the first link not help?

Comment: This is the answer that helped me, thank you @David. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8972088/1194908

Answer (score 1):

For a custom solution here is the idea.

In the filter you need to wrap the response and intercept the output of the servlet, so you can write it.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, 
                     ServletResponse response, 
                     FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {

    // Wrap the response
    MyResponseWrapper responseWrapper = 
                         new MyResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) response);

    chain.doFilter(request, responseWrapper);
}
```

Where MyResponseWrapper is a class where you can intercept all calls to output stream

```
public class MyResponseWrapper implements HttpServletResponse {
     private HttpServletResponse response;
     private ServletOutputStream outputStream;
     private MyOutputStreamCopier myOutputStreamCopier;

     public MyResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response) {
         this.response = response;
     }

     // Implements all needed methods

     // Write methods like the following to redirect output to your logs
     public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
         if (outputStream == null) {
             outputStream = getResponse().getOutputStream();
             copier = new MyOutputStreamCopier(outputStream);
         }

         return copier;
    }
}
```

Where `MyOutputStreamCopier` is a custom class that extends `ServletOutputStream` and copy all writes to a local buffer (or directly log it to a log file).

---

If you like an already build solution take a look at this [link](https://github.com/Naquaduh/SpringMvcTemplate/blob/master/src/main/java/com/alphatek/tylt/web/support/HttpServletResponseCopier.java)

Comment: Lorenzo how can I get the content after doFilter?

Comment: @Armen basically MyOutputStreamCopier needs to buffer the data sent to the output, so you can use them in a second moment. Probably you can add a method String getOutputContent() to retrieve the content as a String. Otherwise you can write directly in the log file in the class MyOutputStreamCopier.